# why the flutter multi entry point did not work as expect

Tags: flutter

I want to using entry-point in my flutter 2.10.3 project, so I tried to write a demo file like this:

```
void main() {
  print("main");
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void entryPoint() {
  print("entry-point");
}
```

when I run this project, it print the `main` but did not print the `entry-point`. why the entry-point did not work? the log output like this:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           19.8s
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64706/lkdcvnIiXyQ=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone Xʀ...
flutter: main
```

Answer (score 1):

you must attach enterpoint method into flutter engine by java and kotlin or swift (write native code) also

follow this article
https://medium.com/@vad.pinchuk/multiple-entry-android-application-with-flutter-or-alternative-ways-to-restrict-access-to-1260e097ef9f